# How to create reports of form view in Openerp-7?

Tags: python, openerp-7

I wanted to know whats is the process of creating reports in my openerp-7 module. Do I have to install some specific module for reporting or is there any default configuration ? I want to create reports of my forms . Like if I want to create report in form view then what am I suppose to do . 
   Hopes for suggestion 
   Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use webkit reports,

- Install report_webkit module in OpenERP
- Install wkhtmltopdf

  in terminal type, `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`
- in terminal type `which wkhtmltopdf` and copy the path
- in OpenERP, Go to Settings->Technical->Parameters->System Parameters

  And create a new record with key 'webkit_path' and paste the path in value field
- Now you can create reports using mako templates
- For testing wkhtmltopdf is working correctly,

  in terminal type, `wkhtmltopdf www.google.com google.pdf`